# Save as Excel in C# can take a long time to be saved

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am creating a new Excel work in C#
however the action of saving As is taking for too long time (couple of minutes)
the excel size I am creating is about 4MB

is there a way to speed it up?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook  xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add("");
```

logic for creating the new WorkBook....

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(); 
//xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(_pathExcel,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

xlWorkBook.Close(true);
xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: try to say ``xlWorkBook.Close(false);`` - you could also try to show the application `xlApp.Visible = true` and save as manually and see how that performs

Comment: It is what it is, it depends on your machine's power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft strongly advise against office automation, 
[specially when it's done at server side.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)

I have not tested these, but there are a number of free c# libaries for this, [check this post out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp)

I used OLEDB to write into excel, which was pretty fast and simple.